# Where should I start for making an AI Bot that processes on screen prompts

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I would love to learn visual AI and what better way than creating a bot to play offline games. The problem is with no experience in AI other than Azure through my college, I have no experience.
Does anyone have resources that could aid in my learning or any tips for getting started? All will be appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, Robotics@SE has an [AI tag](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence).

Answer (score 0):

More generally you should read about [deep reinforcement learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_reinforcement_learning).